# split a binary string with null bytes inside

Tags: erlang

Let a binary string composed of messages separated by one null byte:

```
<message><null><message><null> ... <message><null>
```

I would like to split them. Easy, I do:

```
binary:split(Bin,<<0>>,[global]),
```

But ...
But one message is composed of two parts:

```
<length><texte>
```

length has a 4-bytes fixed size and the length can have null bytes !
Then the split function cannot cut correctly the string.
Does exist a way according to erlang state of art ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all messages have a 4 byte length header, I'd recommend using `erlang:decode_packet(Type,Bin,Options)` where `Type` is set to `4`. This will return `{ok, Message, Rest}` where `Message` is your first message and `Rest` is the rest of the binary. Just rinse and repeate until you reach the end of the binary (you might have to take care of the null bytes yourself inbetween).

If, however, not all messages have a 4 byte length prefix and there's no deterministic way of detecting that header it is probably impossible to reliably parse such a list.

Comment: Good idea ! yes the prefix has a fixed 4-bytes length. With Type we skip the length field and I need it !

Comment: You can check the length with `byte_size(Message)` so I'd suggest using that instead.